# Liquibase Gradle plugin 2.0.2 rollback task error

Tags: sql, gradle, plugins, liquibase

When I try to use "rollback" task I have an error: 
The value for task ':database-module:rollback' property 'mainClass' is final and cannot be changed any further.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are on Gradle 6.4 as the error matches a change that was done in that version.

If so, it's a bug/incompatability in the Liquibase Gradle plugin. Check the progress on it here: https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-gradle-plugin/issues/70

As a work-around, consider using Gradle 6.3 until it is fixed.